# How can I use Proguard in Eclipse for NON-Android Java projects?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard, obfuscation

I have a simple Java `.jar` application, that is not for Android. I want to use ProGuard (Eclipse plugin), to obfuscate its code. However, I could not find any way to use ProGuard Eclipse plugin for non-Android java projects. Can anybody tell me how can I do that?

I can not use the original ProGuard GUI, because my application requires too much obfuscation configuration, that I can not re-enter every time I want to export my application

Thank you.